# logistic regression in Stata error code

Tags: stata, logistic-regression

I have a survey dataset identified by household id and person id. There's a question in the survey about members of the household with disability. Due to the framing of the question, I noticed that the characteristics of the person with disability (e.g. age, educ, etc) were encoded to other members' data.

We were tasked to do logistic regression where the dependent variable is the `disability` variable. When I run `logit` in Stata, I get `error 2000` saying that there are no observations. What am I supposed to do? Should I transfer the observations from the other members' profile to the person with 'disability profile'? This might be the reason why I get the error code in Stata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is marginal for Stack Overflow, which is not really for general questions about software, but more about problems in developing your own Stata programs or code (in this case). Nevertheless Stata users on SO generally try to accommodate this kind of question.

Please note: not only can we not see your dataset, but also you seem to be assuming that we can understand what it is all about from a brief verbal description. In general that is unlikely.

Nevertheless your problem is likely to be very simple. `error 2000` here often means that you have one or more variables that should be numeric in string form. `logit` requires all of the variables fed to it to be numeric. Look carefully at the results of `describe` to see if any of the variables you use is actually string. If so, consider using `destring` or `encode` as appropriate to produce numeric variables.

For future reference: this is generic to essentially all statistical commands in Stata.

It is also possible that `error 2000` reflects a problem with missing values in one or more variables. In that case, look carefully at the results of `summarize` and/or `codebook, compact`.